# How can I include opengl functions in NASM?

Tags: opengl, nasm

I want to write a program with using NASM. How can I include opengl functions in NASM?

I am using linux.

Comment: How would you do it in C?

Comment: How can you include opengl functions in C?

Comment: @user253751 #include <GL/glu.h>

Comment: Same way you'd call any library functions from asm, following the standard calling convention, and for struct definitions, either manually by reading the C headers or using some tool to convert them to NASM definitions.

Comment: An almost-working Windows example: [What's wrong with my NASM OpenGL code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12251861) except it's using NASMX which seems to define a MASM-like `invoke` macro for calling a function.  I guess using info from the `.inc` files which aren't normally needed for calling library functions in Linux.  So probably not really helpful.

Comment: @suiciyom and do you know how `#include <GL/glu.h>` works?